# pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: record "new" is not assigned yet

Tags: php, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL DB and getting below error message..

> pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: record "new" is not assigned yet
>   DETAIL: The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is
>   indeterminate. CONTEXT: SQL statement "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE
>   someid = NEW.someid"

I am calling one PGSQL function from trigger on 'Insert or Update'.

Any help on above error would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you defined the trigger to process on each `STATEMENT` instead of on each `ROW`?

Comment: I think @KouberSaparev has it right.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply guys... I got the cause of above issue. Actually those who created trigger is calling on 'delete' event also. Which is wrong.